# MATLAB displaying legend labels next to plots

Tags: matlab, plot, label, legend

I'm trying to figure out how to mimic a certain behavior I have a screenshot of:

[image]

How are the curves labeled like that? I initially thought it used the `legend` function, but now I suspect it might not be, considering I haven't found any documentation for it that specifies this behavior.

Bonus: How do you specify the centered labels for each of the `fill` functions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text`

```
xmax= %insert upper limit of x-axis here
text(xmax,f2(xmax),'F2','HorizontalAlignment','left')
```

If this does not work, please provide example code producing everything else.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, now based on that I think I can derive the centered text in the areas.

Answer (score 0):

For the labels within the graph, if you don't want to get into the trouble of specifying their position manually, use

```
gtext('string')
```

which lets you place the label with the mouse.

Comment: I just averaged the vertex coordinates of each of the areas for the position of the labels. And I know it's generic enough because I'm only working with convex polygons.